I have fixed all the seeds in Python, but still get different results
This program is to train an agent via reinforcement learning, and the whole algorithm is totally written by myself.
As follows, I have set all the seeds and other details mentioned in other similar questions.
......etc. 

def set_seed(seed):
    os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"]=str(seed)
    random.seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    th.manual_seed(seed)

    if th.cuda.is_available():
        th.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
        th.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
    th.manual_seed(seed)

    th.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
    th.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
    th.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)

set_seed(42)

......etc.

The dataset contains only one data(a scene), so i think it is not the dataloader which raises the problem.  I have removed all the time module. However, the results (loss curve, reward curve, etc.) are different between each training.
The strange thing is that, all the curves are same at first approximate 1 million timesteps but then gradually become diverse.
Image of Curves during Training
Why the curve shows neutral results, shouldn't it be totally different or totally identical?
Thanks very much for any suggestions.
